# Can you import modules into an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a directory that contains only javascript files. Inside each is an `animation()` function that gets exported. My goal is to pick one of these at random to be used.

In another file I would like to import all of these functions into an array, that way I am able to select them randomly in a simple manner.

I tried:

```
var animations=[
  require('./Animations/1.js'),
  require('./Animations/2.js'),
  require('./Animations/3.js'),
]
```

But this didn't work. Is this possible? I'm aware I can just import them all first, then store them in an array, but if there is a way to just import them directly into the array it would be much cleaner.

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be done in an array but maybe you can do something like this. 
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);   and then do this require('./Animations/' + num + '.js');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you type `require('./Animations/1.js')`, etc. you are typing actual program statements ("commands") and not JavaScript objects ("data"). Arrays contain values, not commands.

Having said that, you can have an array of module/ file names, where the names are strings enclosed in quotes. And you can use a variable in a `require` statement, and do anything you want to manipulate and change that variable's value. So if you want to pick a name at random from an array of names, and use that name in a `require` statement, you can certainly do so.

I tried this and it works:

```
var fileNames = [
'mouse',
'bird',
'rabbit'
 ];

var n = Math.floor( Math.random() * fileNames.length );

var url = './' + fileNames[n] + '.js';

require(url);

animate();
```

I used random filenames ('mouse', 'bird', 'rabbit') for my example, because you don't always have names that fit into a nice numerical sequence without gaps. However, if you are certain your names will fit a neat, well defined pattern, you can, of course, structure your code accordingly.

To answer the original question, "Can you import modules into an array?", the answer is Yes, if you really want to do that. If you are starting to work with `require` statements, you may have seen them being used to give values to a variable, like this:

```
var Mouse = require './mouse';
var Bird = require './bird';
var Rabbit = require './rabbit';
```

Then, you could fill an array with actual references to the modules, instead of just their names:

`var modules = [Mouse, Bird, Rabbit];`

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. Not _exactly_ what I was asking but still a useful method that's pretty clean.

Comment: I just added a couple paragraphs to explain how someone could add actual references to the modules, instead of just the module names, if they really wanted to.